# What is the newest version of Netbeans that works with Java 2 (j2sdk1.4.2_19)

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc-odbc

My company is using WebToGo for managing our Service Requests.  I had written a program to extract a list of our service requests in a more faster, more user-friendly way than is otherwise available.  But it used the JDBC-ODBC bridge, which went bye-bye.  So my program stopped working.  I need to send my program out to multiple users, so was looking for a solution that would be easy to implement (trying to get everyone to copy the bridge from JAVA 7 to JAVA 8 would be a big no-no with my IT department).  After digging, I found that WebToGo is still using JAVA 2 (j2sdk1.4.2_19), so there is where I need to go.  But My Netbeans (8.2) wont let me go to a platform that old.  Does anyone know what the latest version of Netbeans would be that would work with j2sdk1.4.2_19?  I dont see it in the documentation and would prefer to avoid downloading and installing all of them until I found the one that works

Comment: Can you write it using a current JDK and just compile and run it using jdk2?

Comment: Have you checked [Netbeans Release Archive](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/old.html)?